# Oracle SQL to Excel - Integration

Tags: sql, oracle, vba, excel

I have MANY (60+) complex queries using different tables and views from an oracle database which I am trying to report in excel.

What would be the most efficient approach in doing so? The query results will also need to vlookup with some pre-assigned values in excel in order to place the outputs accordingly. And the excel file will need to have a VBA macro setup to refresh and update the file when needed.

The applicable method in excel using microsoft query is not efficient. What are the other options? I have tried researching but could not find anything which is very automated and smooth.

Comment: You said you need to use VBA to refresh and update, so you have answer your question already.  Use VBA to connect and retrieve data from oracle.

Comment: I find it hard to believe anything you write in VBA would be more efficient than MS Query.  Invariably, your VBA would have to declare, execute and fetch from the database, just like MS Query, only now you also have to worry about rendering the output.  Why is Excel and MS Query not efficient?  I'm not criticizing -- I really want to understand.

Answer (score 0):

With Excel 2013 onwards the trick is to only use MS Query once and try to avoid having to use VBA.

In a fresh sheet use MS Query to create a very simple against one of you smallest tables and let it return the results in an Excel table. This will get you a refreshable table in Excel with all tricky stuff like connection string completed for you. You can now use this tab as a template.

Copy the entire tab by grabbing it with the Ctrl key held down and drop it in the next tab position. This has the advantage of creating a separate table with a separate Oracle connection. For the new tab, on the data ribbon click the Properties button to bring up the External Data Properties dialog then click the Connection Properties button to the right of the Connection Name and click on the Definition tab. In the Command Text box paste in your complex query, then click OK twice to get your real query populated into Excel.

Repeat the template tab copy and query paste 59+ more times and your done. You can use Refresh All on the Data Ribbon to refresh them all at once. Add other Excel formula/formatting as required. As always, keyboard shortcuts are normally faster than clicks.

Although not mandatory and probably more time consuming than all the above, you should give each connection name, tab and Excel table a proper name. You can use the same one for each of these (character restrictions permitting), so when you've pasted your SQL, fix the Connection Name and copy it so you can paste it into the tab name and table name.

You can set these query tables to automatically refresh when the sheets is opened. Also consider do more of the work in Oracle to reduce the number of query tables especially if it reduces the number of notoriously expensive VLOOKUPs. You can also export your Connection Properties Definition to your My Data Sources directory and reuse it from the Existing Connections button on the Data Ribbon so you may never need to use MS Query again.

All the above can be done in VBA but by the time you've written the code, debugged it and pasted in the parameters like the SQL and the names I believe it would have been quicker and simpler to do the above.